# Paypal Rest Sandbox Error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

When im try to create a Paypal Payment every time i get this Error "Failed to connect to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443: Connection refused"

```
        $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $itemSignup = new Item();
    $itemSignup->setName('Test');
    $itemSignup->setCurrency('EUR');
    $itemSignup->setQuantity(1);
    $itemSignup->setPrice(self::SIGNUP_PRICE);

    $itemList =new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems([$itemSignup]);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
    $amount->setTotal(self::SIGNUP_PRICE);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setItemList($itemList);
    $transaction->setDescription('Test');

    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost/test/');
    $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl('http://localhost/test/');

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('Sale');
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try {
        $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        dd($e->getMessage());
```

Comment: If this is on IIS then your app pool may need to be restarted

Comment: Wait sorry, check your port forwarding. It's probably not liking returning to localhost make sure you "Put Online" and try your actual IP and make sure port 80 is forwarded

Comment: allow_url_fopen is On

Comment: Sorry, I updated that comment

Comment: Check your apache access.log and see if there's SSL handshake error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the firewall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

To create a payment, the url should be:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
```